# Issue with exact match returning wrong results

Tags: mysql

We are having unexpected results from MySQL, we are using the following query...

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl.members` WHERE `referredby` LIKE '%MEM04912%';
```

and it returns correct results(5), but when we try the exact match as following...

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl.members` WHERE `referredby` = 'MEM04912';
```

We only get one result, but correct value is 5, can you help me resolve the same.

Comment: Please, provide some data in your table

Comment: sounds like the other rows have extra characters or whitespace in the `referredby` field, if i am correct in thinking that you mean you should be getting the same number of rows with both queries. You should trim the inputs before entering them into the db.

Answer (score 2):

The two queries are different from each other. The first one looks for a records which **contains** `MEM04912` within column `referredby`, while the second one finds a records that has **exact value** of `MEM04912`.

Given the set of data,

```
referredby
==============
AMEM04912
MEM04912
MEM049123
XMEM04912X
```

when you execute your first query, it will return all records since all of them contains a part of your searched string, while your second query will only return the second record because it is the only record that exactly match on your searched string.

Comment: Beat me by a few seconds XD

Comment: @491243 so why second query is not returning 5 results as well, because there are 5 rows in table for second query

Comment: @seoppc do you mean all records are exactly equal to `MEM04912`? have you check for white spaces on the string?

Comment: YES, there is not any whitespace

Comment: can you provide a demo on regarding your problem? something like this: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e0751/1

Comment: @491243 yes, wait few mins, is `UPDATE tbl.members SET referredby = TRIM(referredby);` correct approach to remove white space is there any

Comment: your `UPDATE` statement is correct. try it first and run the query again.

Comment: above UPDATE query returns 0 rows affected.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl.members` WHERE `referredby` LIKE '%MEM04912%';
```

Gives you results like MEM049121, AMEM04912 and so on.

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl.members` WHERE `referredby` = 'MEM04912';
```

Gives you only the result where the referredby is exactly MEM04912 with no extra characters or numbers added in front of or behind MEM04912

Answer (score 0):

If you query ...

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl.members` WHERE `referredby` LIKE '%MEM04912%';
```

you'll get all results where column `referredby` contains the String `MEM04912`, e.g. `SOMEMEM04912`, `MEM04912MORE`, etc.  If you execute ...

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl.members` WHERE `referredby` = 'MEM04912';
```

you get only columns, where `referredby` is exactly equal to `MEM04912`.